# Stabilize 2D Node Creates Jumpy Renders

Tags: tracking

The stabilize 2D node in the compositor continues to produce jumpy renders on my computer. When I export using this node, the video jumps about every 30 frames.

Here is my setup in the compositor:
[image]

Here is what the output usually looks like:

https://youtu.be/PIEDARkL7iI

Note: The renders look fine when I use only transform nodes and offset them using the movie clips x,y, and angle outputs. I like how clean the compositor is when using the Stablize 2D node, so I would like to figure this out. Maybe it is my old macbook pro Mid 2010 that is having trouble.

Comment: I've not actually used the Stabilize 2D node before but it seems very wrong to me to have the image going through two opposing stabilize nodes like that. Surely you should be "stabilizing" either the original footage (the first, non-inverted node) and then adding the overlay without any additional stabilization, or using the inverted stabilization on just the image before overlaying it.

Comment: I gather that you are stabilising footage to add another image then reintroducing the camera movement. But I'm confused about what you call jumpy movement? It could be that the movie source is not decompressing correctly. Go back to the Movie Clip Editor and generate timecode for the footage. This should make it easier for Blender to recognise the correct frame order. Or you'll have to prerender as a frame sequence.

Comment: Why are you using two stabilize nodes?

Comment: It re-introduces the camera shake if you have it set to invert